# Unable to parse date from line java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date

Tags: java, simpledateformat

Error:

> Unable to parse date from line java.text.ParseException: Unparseable
>   date: "2018-07-26 12.38.35.520"

Code:

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.US);
    return formatter.parse(stringDate);
```

Tried with and without Local too.

Comment: Your input date string has the time components separated by dots, not colons.  So maybe try using the mask `yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss.SSS`.

Comment: Such a small (BIG?) mistake I made to use ":" instead of ".".

Comment: Tim Beigeleisen, dead eye ,Thanks a lot!!

Comment: `2018-07-26 12.38.35.520`  --> `2018-07-26 12:38:35.520`

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Just as a detail, the corresponding exception message from *java.time* will mention the parse position where parsing failed, for example “index 13”, which will help identifying that the mismatch between dot and colon is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Pattern is not matching your String try the following:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss.SSS", Locale.US);
return formatter.parse(stringDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

input Date is not in correct format. Change it to 2018-07-26 12:38:35.520